# How to rename default category name and slug using WP CLI?

Tags: wp-cli

Using WP CLI how can I rename default category (Uncategorized) to **Blog** when starting a new project?

Following [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/term/) this should be correct?

```
wp term update category 1 --name="Blog"
```

But I get error

```
Term doesn't exist
```

This is how `wp_terms` table looks like

[image]

**EDIT**

If I first create a category Blog with `wp term create category Blog`, how would I set this new category as default?
After that I could try deleting the first category Uncategorized with `wp term delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the quotes around the new name. The docs show it as:

`wp term update category 1 --name=Blog`

Comment: I have tried, it gives me same error :)

Comment: Are you sure it's in the category taxonomy? Is this a multisite?

Comment: It is not multisite and it is regular category

Comment: What happens if you run `wp term get category 1`?

Comment: Hm I also get error "Term doesn't exist". I have also tried just adding new category and immeadiatelly retrieveing it, the error is same https://image.prntscr.com/image/lOyc92tkQGyWDS45zXLzoA.jpeg Listing categories gives correct terms... https://image.prntscr.com/image/1lMNV095TnONhP--q2C-_A.jpeg

Comment: Are you calling this from the site root? I have a feeling you may be in the wrong directory.

Comment: Yes, I am trying this from Wordpress root (Test project, clean new installation), I have also tried it within my theme and everything else works the same but this category retrieving seems half-working and bugged...

Comment: Do you see your categories when you run `wp term list category`?